# How can I progam directly on my web server

Tags: javascript, web-services, angular

Is there a way for me to be able to write programs directly on my web server and when I save the files they are automatically saved on my server without having anything saved on my computer itself?

Comment: You could develop on your server, using Teamviewer or Remote desktop. However I don't recommend doing so. Why would you want to do this? Do you mean saving automatically means an update for the production application?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. Could you make it clear, please ?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Ideally you write on a machine on which you can debug your code (locally), then deploy once you're confident that it works.  That's why there are sarcastic shirts about testing in production.

Comment: the server is just meant for development services. @Max

Answer (score 0):

I also **don't** recommend doing so, but you have several options:

1. Remote connection with Remote desktop, Tiemviewer, etc...
2. Mounting your remote file system with `ssh`, `smb`, etc...
3. You can also with some IDEs, open your file with `ftp` and when you save it, it uploads it